# C# : parameterize SQL insert statement when column names contain spaces and special characters

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, prepared-statement

I have a SQL Server database that contains column names with spaces and special characters. Just for  demonstration purposes let's say these column names are as follows...

1. Item ID
2. Item's Name
3. Price, of Item

In the past I've made use of SQL parameters when inserting data into SQL Server; however, when I try now with brackets surrounding the parameter names that contain special characters I get an exception

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'. Must declare the scalar variable "@".'

Is it possible to create a parameterized queries in C# if the database table column names contain spaces and special characters?

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new 
SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = "[My Server Name]";
builder.UserID = "[My User ID]";
builder.Password = "[My Password]";
builder.InitialCatalog = "[My Database Name]";
string tableName = "dbo.test_GroceryList";
string columns = "[Item ID],[Item's Name],[Price, of Item]";
string values = "@[Item ID],@[Item's Name],@[Price, of Item]";
string sqlCommandInsert = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0}({1} VALUES({2})", tableName, columns, values);  
using (var con = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandInsert, con))
{
  con.Open();
 cmd.Parameters.Clear();
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Item ID]", "1");
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Item's Name]", "Milk");
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Price, of Item]", "1.99");
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but you have to show your code.

Comment: Can you show us your code (that's resulting in the error you do show)?

Comment: Why do you want your parameter names to have special characters? Just give them a name that doesn't force such silliness.

Comment: This almost seems like you are naming your parameter just @. It needs something more like @p1. cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarchar, 255). Value = "hfldjahl";

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to do something like this:

```
int retVal = 0;
string sql = @"SELECT [sold]
                  FROM [some_datebase].[dbo].[nvdr_sales]
                  WHERE [store id] = @store_id
                  AND [report date] = @report_date;";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@store_id", d.id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report_date", date);
    connection.Open();
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            retVal = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("sold"));
        }
    }
    connection.Close();
}
return retVal;
```

Comment: This looks pretty good but I would suggest not using AddWithValue. It can cause all sorts of issues. https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/ or https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Also not sure the point of iterating over the result set.

Comment: There is no point to this code other than highlighting that spaces can be used.  The question needs some work.